# EF7 "Invalid Object Name 'xyz'" when manually scaffolding existing database

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I've published a DB using an SqlDatabase Project.

I've manually created POCO classes, as well as a Db context to match the published database.

Whenever I try to execute an EF statement, valid SQL Query is generated, but I receive the error

```
An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query.
  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name '[xyz]'
```

The properties on the EF class match exactly type/nullable/name/etc in the database.  The query generated, when run manually works fine.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you run your EF database commands on the command line? dnx ef migrations-add NewXYZCol and dnx ef database update? Your db will not have the object b/c you have to add it using these commands...

Comment: No - the EF7 tooling on the RC2 chain appears to be FUBAR from what I can tell right now.   Also, I'm not a huge fan conceptually of EF migrations vs intentionally scripting a database. 

That said, I clearly outlined that I'm attempting to "manually scaffold" the database which I believe should indicate that ef-migrations add doesn't apply.

The tables and columns exist, the POCOs exist with corresponding fields.  The ApiDBContext exists and EF is generating correct SQL - the only problem seems to be the materialization of the result back into the POCO - but the message is ambiguous.

Comment: Can you update your question with the POCO and the sql that EF generated? Also, if you execute the sql from something else, like the SQL Server Explorer in VS, does the sql query work?

Comment: Sorry I can't provide any more info - I've had to revert this project back to an earlier version of RC2 that ran on DNX.   I could copy paste the SQL out of the Kestrel console and it worked fine though. 

That said, once I ran scaffold process on the dnx tooling I noticed it generates a lot of code in OnModelCreating related to column dataTypes, max lengths and default values... my guess is it is something related to that having been missing from my POCOs that was blocking the materialization of the result into an entity.   

Anyway I'll close since I can't provide anything more useful.